# hi, i was recently refused uk tourism visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

"i have considered you personal and economic circumstances, however i note that your partner is funding for this trip, you state that your partner is providing xxamount for the trip but i notice he only has XX amount in bank, which is less than the amount u have stated, so we refuse this visa under V 3 (c).

i had provided my partner's as well as my bank statement, my partner had transferred money into my account for the trip, but i had written that my partner will be supporting the trip; hence they refused saying that your partner doesn't have enough money in the bank to support me. but the money has already been transferred into my bank.. how can i correct this mistake next time? i am a student and my partner is also a masters student .he gets monthly stipend from college while i dont get, how can i apply next time?

Comment: That type of refusal is massively common.  You'll need to study the linked articles (there are 5 of them) and then make a fresh application.